# Discount code for 4 products only

Tags: magento-1.8, ce-1.8.1.0, discount

How do I set up a discount code that:

1. can only be used once by a single customer
2. applies a 50% discount to only 4 products in the basket, leaving the rest at full price
3. the discount only applies to products in the ticket category and not merchandise

I run a music festival and sell tickets and merchandise through Magento (Community 1.8.1)

We have traders at the event, and offer them up to 4 half price tickets.

I have searched this forum and Google, but can't find anything that matches my requirement.

Comment: only 4   specific  products?

Comment: Amit, yes, any 4 tickets, but only 4.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a shopping cart discount rule with a particular coupon code making the setting uses per customer set to yes.

You can apply a category filter in the conditions tab.

For point b you will need a third party extension to accomplish it.